# PHP mail() not sending email except on gmail

Tags: php, email

I've written a mail script as;

```
<?php
$to = 'something@domain.com';
$subject = 'This is subject!';
$body = 'Welcome to our website!';
$headers = 'From: myemail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: myemail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sent) {
    echo "Your mail has been sent to ". $to .".";
} else {
    echo "You mail was not sent.";
}
?>
```

And I could see the echo "Your mail has been sent to someone@somedomain.com" for mail being sent in all of the cases regardless of what email is **but the emails are being delivered only** to **something@gmail.com but never** on **something@hotmail.com** or **something@yahoo.com or something@domain.com (hosted on google apps)**.

I wonder if there is any server configuration missing or the server has been blocked for hotmail/yahoomail or any error there is? Is there any thing you guys can help/suggest me for this?

I've configured my cPanel mail to be recieved at google apps, but I think that doesn't matter as I am trying to send mail, not recieve with this code here.

And yes, I've tried checking in the SPAM/JUNK folders and also waited lots of minutes to see them not being delivered. ;(

Comment: check the mail response in your logs

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check sender email sendbox also ,there may be mail in sendbox with some error message. or it may be that on your  host the reverse DNS wasn't setup correctly..thanks.

Comment: Hi! Where do i find 'email sendbox' in cPanel?

Comment: Hi If you are using your domain email account for sending email then in cpanel there is Email Account options, you have to first click opn it then it will be display a list of emails from there you can access you mails.else if you are using gmail/yahoo email account for sending mail then you have to go those email sendbox. Your code is working for gmail it means there is no problem in code it must be some hosting dns setup problem...thanks

Comment: have you got the reason behind problem..or solution

Comment: I am trying to use the PHPMailer Class for this purpose. Yet still I haven't got any solution for the problem I stated in this question. I have told my server-support team for that but I still am waiting for their response.

Answer (score 0):

You must authenticate your email with your password before sending, so it won't get blocked in the server. if you use mail class like phpmailer to send mails, following example will help you.

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP  
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username

$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
```

[Php mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) -- Download phpmailer in this website.
[SMTP demo](http://phpcode.mypapit.net/sending-mail-using-smtp-with-phpmailer/26/) -- Nice tutorial how to use php mailer to send authenticated mails.